# Errors saving items to Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm getting a very bizarre errors when I save an objects to a room database.  None of the actual parameters are null.  None of the insert calls fail.  When I inspect the database I see my Junction tables aren't getting populated. This code worked in the past when I was using fixture data.  However that fixture data did not include any null values.  Here is the json that is used in my API to generate my objects.

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "job": {
        "city": "Toronto",
        "job_id": 1,
        "owner_id_map": 1,
        "status": 0,
        "title": "500 Posters in Toronto"
      },
      "posters": [
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 1,
            "latitude": 43.64526533333377,
            "locationDescription": "Union Station",
            "longitude": -79.38060468539248,
            "poster_id": 1,
            "qr_code": "code2",
            "worker_id": 1
          },
          "worker": [
            {
              "workerName": "Jack",
              "worker_id": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 1,
            "latitude": 43.64295669900133,
            "locationDescription": "Queen and Spadina",
            "longitude": -79.39368099382459,
            "poster_id": 2,
            "qr_code": "code3",
            "worker_id": 2
          },
          "worker": [
            {
              "workerName": "Jack",
              "worker_id": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 1,
            "latitude": 43.76892443268843,
            "locationDescription": "North York Civic Center",
            "longitude": -79.41292484238735,
            "poster_id": 3,
            "qr_code": "code4",
            "worker_id": 3
          },
          "worker": [
            {
              "workerName": "Nicky",
              "worker_id": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "workers": [
        {
          "workerName": "Noris",
          "worker_id": 1
        },
        {
          "workerName": "Jack",
          "worker_id": 2
        },
        {
          "workerName": "Nicky",
          "worker_id": 3
        },
        {
          "workerName": "Davis",
          "worker_id": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "job": {
        "city": "Montreal",
        "job_id": 2,
        "owner_id_map": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "title": "20 Posters in Montreal"
      },
      "workers": [
        {
          "workerName": "Jack",
          "worker_id": 2
        },
        {
          "workerName": "Nicky",
          "worker_id": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "job": {
        "city": "Ottawa",
        "job_id": 3,
        "owner_id_map": 2,
        "status": 2,
        "title": "350 Posters in Ottawa"
      },
      "posters": [
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 3,
            "latitude": 43.63904362027761,
            "locationDescription": "Harbourfront",
            "longitude": -79.38193214610098,
            "poster_id": 4,
            "qr_code": "code5",
            "worker_id": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 3,
            "latitude": 43.68347235901327,
            "locationDescription": "Bathurst and St Clair",
            "longitude": -79.41851002097324,
            "poster_id": 5,
            "qr_code": "code6",
            "worker_id": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 3,
            "latitude": 43.6958481647278,
            "locationDescription": "Dufferin and Eglinton",
            "longitude": -79.45035794609939,
            "poster_id": 6,
            "qr_code": "code7",
            "worker_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "workers": [
        {
          "workerName": "Noris",
          "worker_id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "job": {
        "city": "Calgary",
        "job_id": 4,
        "owner_id_map": 2,
        "status": 0,
        "title": "10 Posters in Calgary"
      },
      "posters": [
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 4,
            "latitude": 43.64526533333377,
            "locationDescription": "Union Station",
            "longitude": -79.38060468539248,
            "poster_id": 7,
            "qr_code": "code2",
            "worker_id": 1
          },
          "worker": [
            {
              "workerName": "Noris",
              "worker_id": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 4,
            "latitude": 43.64295669900133,
            "locationDescription": "Queen and Spadina",
            "longitude": -79.39368099382459,
            "poster_id": 9,
            "qr_code": "code3",
            "worker_id": 2
          },
          "worker": [
            {
              "workerName": "Jack",
              "worker_id": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "poster": {
            "job_id_map": 4,
            "latitude": 43.76892443268843,
            "locationDescription": "North York Civic Center",
            "longitude": -79.41292484238735,
            "poster_id": 8,
            "qr_code": "code4",
            "worker_id": 3
          },
          "worker": [
            {
              "workerName": "Nicky",
              "worker_id": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "workers": [
        {
          "workerName": "Noris",
          "worker_id": 1
        },
        {
          "workerName": "Jack",
          "worker_id": 2
        },
        {
          "workerName": "Nicky",
          "worker_id": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "owners": [
    {
      "ownerName": "Jason",
      "owner_id": 1
    },
    {
      "ownerName": "Becky",
      "owner_id": 2
    },
    {
      "ownerName": "Andrew",
      "owner_id": 3
    }
  ],
  "status": "success",
  "users": {
    "A": {
      "email": "A",
      "name": "A",
      "password": "A",
      "username": "A"
    },
    "a": {
      "email": "a",
      "name": "a",
      "password": "a",
      "username": "a"
    },
    "a`a`a": {
      "email": "a",
      "name": "a`a`a",
      "password": "a",
      "username": "a`a`"
    },
    "a`a`a`": {
      "email": "a",
      "name": "a`a`a`",
      "password": "a",
      "username": "a"
    },
    "aa": {
      "email": "a",
      "name": "aa",
      "password": "a",
      "username": "a"
    },
    "aa`": {
      "email": "a",
      "name": "aa`",
      "password": "a",
      "username": "a"
    },
    "q": {
      "email": "a",
      "name": "q",
      "password": "a",
      "username": "a"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code where I insert the data

```
    override suspend fun saveJobToDatabase(job: JobPW): Long {
        var jobId : Long = 0

        jobId = jobsDao.insertJob(job.job)
        jobsDao.insertWorkers(job.workers)
        job.workers.forEach {
            jobsDao.insertWorker(it)
            jobsDao.insertJobWorkerCrossRef(JobWorkerCrossRef(job.job.job_id, it.worker_id))
        }
        try {
            if (job?.posters?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                jobsDao.insertPostersWithWorkers(job.posters, jobId)
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Posters are empty")
            }
        } catch (ex : Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error saving posters to database", ex)
        }

//        job.posters.forEach {
//            jobsDao.insertPosterWorkerCrossRef(PosterWorkerCrossRef(it.poster.poster_id, it.worker.get(0).worker_id))
//        }
        return jobId
```

Here is the code for the insert posters method

```
  @Transaction
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertPostersWithWorkers(poster: List<PosterWithWorker>, jobId : Long) {
        poster?.forEach {
            if (it?.worker != null && it.worker.isNotEmpty()) {
                it.worker.forEach {
                    insertWorker(it)
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "worker is null or empty for job ${jobId}")
            }
            if (it?.poster != null)  {
                insertPoster(it.poster)
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "poster is empty for job ${jobId}")
            }


            //not all posters have workers assigned to them
            if (it.worker != null && it.worker!=null && it.worker.isNotEmpty() && it.worker[0].worker_id != 0L && it.poster.poster_id != 0L) {
                insertPosterWorkerCrossRef(
                    PosterWorkerCrossRef(
                        it.poster.poster_id,
                        it.worker[0].worker_id
                    )
                )
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "worker or poster is empty for job ${jobId}")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the database insert statements

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertJob(job: Job) : Long

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWorkers(workers: List<Worker>)
    
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertPoster(poster: Poster)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWorker(worker: Worker)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertJobWorkerCrossRef (crossRef: JobWorkerCrossRef)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertJobPosterCrossRef (crossRef: JobWorkerCrossRef)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertPosterWorkerCrossRef(it: PosterWorkerCrossRef)
```

Here is a snapshot of my database tables

Job table is ok

[image: Job Table]

Worker table is ok

[image: Worker Table]

Poster table is missing the poster with id 8 & 9

[image: Poster Table]

For some reason the job -> worker cross reference table isn't getting populated properly.  This is the main problem.

[image: Job Worker Cross Reference]

Owner table is ok

[image: Owner]

This seems to be ok as there are no workers assigned for poster 4, 5 & 6.

[image: Poster Worker Junction Table]

Here are the entities

Job

```
data class Job (


    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    @SerializedName("job_id")
    @field:Json(name = "job_id")
    @JsonProperty("job_id")
    val job_id: Long = 0,

    @SerializedName("status")
    @field:Json(name = "status")
    @JsonProperty("status")
    val status: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("owner_id_map")
    @field:Json(name = "owner_id_map")
    @JsonProperty("owner_id_map")
    val owner_id_map: Int = 0,

    @field:Json(name = "title")
    @JsonProperty("title")
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String = "",

    @SerializedName("city")
    @field:Json(name = "city")
    @JsonProperty("city")
    val city: String = "",


) : Serializable
```

Worker

```
@Entity
class Worker(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "worker_id")
    @JsonProperty("worker_id")
    val worker_id: Long,

    @JsonProperty("workerName")
    val workerName: String,
) : Serializable
```

Poster

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Job::class,
            parentColumns = ["job_id"],
            childColumns = ["job_id_map"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Poster (
    @JsonProperty("poster_id")
    @PrimaryKey val poster_id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    @JsonProperty("job_id_map")
    val job_id_map: Long,
    @JsonProperty("qr_code")
    val qr_code: String,
    @JsonProperty("worker_id")
    val worker_id: Long,
    @JsonProperty("latitude")
    val latitude: Double,
    @JsonProperty("longitude")
    val longitude: Double,
    @JsonProperty("locationDescription")
    val locationDescription: String,
    )
```

Job Worker Junction Table

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["job_id","worker_id"], /* composite primary key */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Job::class,
            parentColumns = ["job_id"],
            childColumns = ["job_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Worker::class,
            parentColumns = ["worker_id"],
            childColumns = ["worker_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class JobWorkerCrossRef(
    val job_id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val worker_id: Long,
)
```

Poster worker cross reference table.  I used the poster as a primary key to restrict one worker per poster.  So this disallows and poster relationship showing up twice

```
@Entity()
data class PosterWorkerCrossRef (
    @PrimaryKey
    val poster_id_map: Long,
    val worker_id_map: Long,
)
```

Poster With Worker Relation (poster object)

```
data class PosterWithWorker(

    @JsonProperty("poster")
    @Embedded val poster: Poster,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "worker_id",
        entityColumn = "worker_id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = PosterWorkerCrossRef::class,
            parentColumn = "poster_id_map",
            entityColumn = "worker_id_map"
        )
    )
    @JsonProperty("worker")
    val worker:  List<Worker>
) : Serializable
```

Job with workers and posters

```
data class JobPW(

    @field:Json(name = "job")
    @JsonProperty("job")
    @SerializedName("job")
    @Embedded val job: Job,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "job_id",
        entityColumn = "worker_id",
        associateBy = Junction(JobWorkerCrossRef::class)
    )
    @SerializedName("workers")
    @field:Json(name = "workers")
    @JsonProperty("workers")
    val workers: List<Worker>,

    @SerializedName("posters")
    @field:Json(name = "posters")
    @JsonProperty("posters")
    @Relation(
        entity = Poster::class,
        parentColumn = "job_id",
        entityColumn = "job_id_map"
    )
    val posters: List<PosterWithWorker>

) : Serializable
```

Please let me know if there is any other information that would be helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to read this long post

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace.

Comment: Please put you entity code here.

Comment: the exception means that you are calling isEmpty() on some null object. but neither the stacktrace is complete nor the code. Please complete details